# Python: Read different lines from a file with threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, line, python-multithreading

So I'm trying to use threading to make a program. The program needs to read 5 different lines with threading as 5 from a text file, with no duplicate lines. Then after it reads the lines it needs to use the different lines in a function with threading. So for example it reads 5 lines, 1 of them being a duplicate so 4 different lines in total. It needs to use the 4 different lines in a function with threads as the number of different lines it found. If the explanation is bad, please ask me questions and I will answer them.

This is everything I have done so far:

```
import random
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

FILENAME = 'testing/pokens.csv'
NTHREADS = 5

def myfunc():
    with open(FILENAME) as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
        line = random.choice(lines).strip()
        tokens = line.split(':')
        return ' '.join(tokens)

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        printable = set()
        for _ in range(NTHREADS):
            future = executor.submit(myfunc)
            futures.append(future)
        for future in futures:
            printable.add(future.result())
        for p in printable:
            print(p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It reads the lines, it removes the duplicates but I just cannot seem to figure out how do I use different lines in a function with threading.

Comment: *"Questions asking for homework help [...] must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."* -- from the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Can you try to show some code we can help you with ?